# What could be the reason for this invalid objects after trying to upgrade?

Tags: oracle, upgrade, errors, audit, oracle-19c

We recently wanted to upgrade our Database but didnt get to do it as we got a lot of Audit specific invalid objects, after looking online for ressources we couldnt find anything specific reason for this happening

This ones are currently Invalid:

```
SYS DBA_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL VIEW
PUBLIC  DBA_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL SYNONYM
SYS CDB_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL VIEW
PUBLIC  CDB_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL SYNONYM
SYS DBA_COMMON_AUDIT_TRAIL  VIEW
PUBLIC  DBA_COMMON_AUDIT_TRAIL  SYNONYM
SYS CDB_COMMON_AUDIT_TRAIL  VIEW
PUBLIC  CDB_COMMON_AUDIT_TRAIL  SYNONYM
SYS FGA_LOG$FOR_EXPORT  VIEW
SYS DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL PACKAGE
PUBLIC  DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL SYNONYM
SYS DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL PACKAGE BODY
```

I already tried recompiling them utlrp also didnt work.

```
alter package DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL compile body;

Warning: Package Body altered with compilation errors.



Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
10:04:39 abc> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL:



LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/14 PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL' without its
specification


1/14 PLS-00905: object SYS.DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have sufficient reputation to comment yet)

Have you compiled the package spec? And what happen when you compile the views?

```
alter package DBMS_AUDIT_UTIL compile;
alter view FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL VIEW compile;
```